# Disable Slide to Lock

Tags: lock-screens, adb

I have a Cruz T301 which is rooted.  The screen calibration is a bit off and I cannot access the home screen. (It is next to impossible to use the slide to unlock.)  Basically, it will slide to the right, but not far enough to unlock.  I know that the app "nolock" will correct this problem, but since I cannot even access the home screen, I am unsure how to turn on this app.

I have tired three different ROMS (Official Cruz, SJHill, and the Davik.)

If I could find the ADB shell command to disable the slide lock, I think I could save this tablet.  I have tried the adb shell input keyevent 82, but it will not work.

I also have Android Commander installed on my PC.  With this I can install apps, just not access the features.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried installing the No Lock app from the web-based play store?

Comment: @TomG I guess he had -- or he wouldn't have it mentioned in his Q: *I know that the app "nolock" will correct this problem, but since I cannot even access the home screen, I am unsure how to turn on this app.*

Comment: @Izzy - I meant that he should install it from the web store, which *might* turn it on automatically (the description in the store seems to indicate that it is enabled by default).   Some Android users don't realize you can trigger an app install from the web.

Comment: @TomG Ah, I see. You didn't give that reason initially, so Todd might have missed it as well ;)